# JMeter Distributed Slave remote start error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

while running J-Meter distributed test on slave machine with single slave user, i am getting below ssl certificate error after selecting 'Remote Start' with slave IP address under 'Run' Menu in master machine.My master and slave machine have Jmeter 5.2 version, connected with same network .

i did below setting before running remote start.

Slave Machine:- server.rmi.ssl.disable =true (commented this property ) and run J-Meter -server Service bat file in slave machine

Master Machine: mention slave ip address in' remote_hosts'  for jmeter.properties and save it and run remote start with slave IP address from master machine

Could you please assist me for the same ?
[image]
Thanks

Amit G

Answer (score 0):

The error means that JMeter master cannot securely connect to the slave, most probably you made a typo or did something wrong, like commented the property while it needs to be **uncommented**

1. If you need secure communication between master and slave(s) follow steps from [Setting up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) chapter of the [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) chapter of the JMeter User Manual
2. If you don't need the secure communication add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
   ```

   - Make sure that the property doesn't have `#` at the beginning and there are no whitespaces at the beginning/end of the line
   - Make sure to restart JMeter to pick up the property
   - This has to be done on JMeter master and all the slaves